# How to integrate a sum function into my Haskell function?

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

My function will replace will any number in the string to 3 and any character to 4. For example "foo123" will be replaced to "444333". My question is how do I convert the "444333" into list in order to use the sum function. "444333" -> [4,4,4,3,3,3] -> sum [4,4,4,3,3,3] = 21

This my code

```
replaceString [] = []
replaceString (x:xs) =
      if x `elem` ['0'..'9']
      then '3' :replaceString xs
      else if x `elem` ['a'..'z']
      then '4' : replaceString xs
      else x : replaceString xs
```

Comment: What error are you facing and where are you stuck ?

Comment: I would like to know how to implement the sum function into my function. sum[xs] doesn't work

Comment: `"444333"` is just syntactic sugar for `['4', '4', '4', '3', '3', '3']`. (The `OverloadedString` extension complicates that a little.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `replaceString` already returns a List of characters but I guess you want to obtain a list of numbers, the answer is just to replace `'3'` and `'4'` with `3` and `4` :), so it will become like this :

```
replaceString [] = []
replaceString (x:xs) = (if x `elem` ['0'..'9']
                       then 3
                       else 4) : replaceString xs
```

Notice that we don't need to repeat `: replaceString xs` :) .

Alternatively if you want to convert a list of digit characters into a list of numbers you could get character's "ordinal" and subtract 48 from it, in haskell the character's ordinal can be obtained by `fromEnum char`, with replaceString putting `'3'` and `'4'`(instead of numbers), we can define a function like this :

```
convertToDigits numstr = map ((48 -) . fromEnum) numstr
```

By the way your original function doesn't convert any other character into 4 but only alphabetic characets, so for `foo21!` the result would be `44433!` and you wouldn't want to sum that, if you want to filter digits I suggest you filter the string from non-alphanumeric characters before even calling `replaceString`.

### Edit :

As Thomas pointed out, you can replace `(48 -) . fromEnum` with `digitToInt` (needs to be imported from `Data.Char`).

Comment: Also consider [`digitToInt`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:digitToInt)

Answer (score 1):

This could also be done by foldl as follows;

```
import Data.Char
getsum :: String -> Int
getsum = foldl helper 0
         where helper n c | isLetter c = n + 3
                          | isNumber c = n + 4
                          | otherwise  = n
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use map and read it should works great

```
funct l = map(\x ->read [x]::Int) l

sum funct("444333") = 21
```